# Query on nodejs promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new learner of javascript. I want to print the list of files in a directory and then print "completed" after listing all the files. Curretnly it is listing only the files in directory but not the "completed" text. I am not able to use promises properly. Can someone please help

```
var fs = require('fs');

f();

function f() {    
    match().then(result => console.log(result));
  } 

async function match() {
    await new Promise(resolve => {        
        return f1(resolve)
    });
    return "dir listing completed"
  }

  function f1() {
    fs.readdir("templates", (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file)
        })
    })   
  }
```

Comment: You pass `resolve` in `f1(resolve)` but `f1` doesn't do anything with any arguments.

Comment: The question is closed so I can't post an answer, but `import { promises } from "fs";

async function match() { const files = await promises.readdir("templates"); for( let file in files){ console.log(file); } console.log("Completed");}`

Comment: Thanks alot! @JeremyThille. The code is working fine after adding 2 lines "const fs = require('fs');
const promises = fs.promises;". But there is a warning "(node:24296) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental"

Comment: `import { promises } from "fs"` should work just as fine. I'm using it all the time. I don't have this warning in Node 14

Answer (score -1):

```
var fs = require('fs');

f1().then(()=>{
    console.log('Completed);
});

function f1() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {      
        fs.readdir("templates", (err, files) => {
            files.forEach(file => {
                console.log(file)
        });
        resolve();
    })   

  })
}
```

Comment: That resolves before the asynchronous `readdir` operation has finished.

Comment: Code is correct and working except I missed the single closing quote at the end of  'Completed', kindly mark it as correct.

Comment: Even ignoring the type (which you could fix with an edit): It doesn't meet the requirements in the question. It is not correct. The Promise here is completely pointless.